# Fill rest of Linearlayout with Edittext (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to fill the rest of the Linearlayout (code below) with an Edittext
how can i do so without using the weight property so the Title (Picture below)
stays as it is?

[image: This is the Picture (Red part)]

Code:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Title"
                android:inputType="textShortMessage"
                android:maxlines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLength="10"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_
            android:padding="10dp">

            <EditText

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Textext"
                android:hint="text"
                android:inputType="textShortMessage"
                android:maxlines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLength="10"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

Comment: Either use `layout_weight`, use something other than `LinearLayout`, or go through some nasty calculations in Java to try to size it yourself. What is your specific objection to using `layout_weight` in this case?

Comment: You've set orientation of Linearlayout to horizontal, change it to vertical and set edittext height to match_parent will solve your issue.... Hope this will give you your desired solution.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent TextInputView is wrap content. Set it to match parent. Else it's just going to fill the wrapped editText instead of filling.